# error: Uncaught TypeError: n.split is not a function

Tags: javascript

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  n.toString()
  let x = n.split('')
  while (x.length != 1) {
    let root = 0
    x.forEach(function(digit) {
      root += Number.parseInt(digit, 10)
    })
    x = root
  }
  return x
}
console.log(digital_root(22))
```

При сплите выводит ошибку error: Uncaught TypeError: n.split is not a function
n - целочисленное, программа складывает цифры в числе пока число не станет одной цифрой

Comment: потому что результат выполнения n.toString() совсем не такой, как вы думаете..

Answer (score 2):

`n.toString()` не изменяет объект `n`, а возвращает результат приведения типа.
Вы этот результат никак не используете.
Должно быть так:

```
n = n.toString();
```

Либо, применительно к Вашему коду:

```
let x = n.toString().split( '' );
```

P.S. При написании кода на JavaScript рекомендуется явно использовать `;` в конце команды.

Comment: Спасибо, два дня изучаю js, Владилен Минин на youtube советует не использовать ; так как выглядит не красиво и не лаконично.
Ваш ответ помог, но теперь похожая ошибка - error: "Uncaught TypeError: x.forEach is not a function"

Comment: На второй итерации цикла `x=root`, то есть х стало числом, а не массивом, поэтому оно не содержит функции `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  let x = n.toString().split('');
  while (x.length > 1) {
    x = (n = x.reduce((r, d) => r += +d, 0)).toString().split('');
  }
  return n;
}

console.log(digital_root(22));
console.log(digital_root(999));
console.log(digital_root(9991));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]